# Codeigniter insert ID number with string into the database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, insert

I'm new to codeigniter and having trouble inserting an ID number with string with it. Can anyone help me how to save it into the database?

Ex. PM0001

Everytime I save it into the database only the number "1" appears in my column ID, but when I retrieve it from the database it displays the ID number "PM0001" into the html table.

My Controller:

```
public function enroll(){
    $data['title'] = "enroll";

    $this->load->model('addschool_model');
    $data['school'] = $this->addschool_model->getAll();
    $this->load->view('admin/view_enroll', $data);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('admin/view_enroll');

    } else {
        $this->load->model('stud_model');

        $udata['school'] = $this->input->post('school');
        $udata['pword'] = $this->input->post('password');
        $udata['fname'] = $this->input->post('fname');
        $udata['lname'] = $this->input->post('lname');
        $udata['contact'] = $this->input->post('contact');
        $udata['address'] = $this->input->post('address');

        $res = $this->stud_model->insert_user_to_db($udata);

        if ($res){
            redirect('admin/enroll');

        }

    }

}
```

My Model:

```
public function insert_user_to_db($udata) {
    return $this->db->insert('students', $udata);

}
```

My View:

```
<tr class="data" >
    <td><?php echo "PM00".$u_key->ID; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $u_key->PWORD; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $u_key->SCHOOL; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $u_key->FNAME; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $u_key->LNAME; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $u_key->CONTACT; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $u_key->ADDRESS; ?></td>
    <td width="40" align="left"><a id="action" href="#" onClick="show_confirm('edit',<?php echo $u_key->ID; ?>)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></a></td>
    <td width="40" align="left"><a id="action" href="#" onClick="show_confirm('delete',<?php echo $u_key->ID; ?>)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></a></td>
</tr>
```

I think my view is ok because the table displays what I wanted to be displayed.
I just want the ID to be displayed in my database the same as the table in my view.

ID in my database: ID = 1
ID in my table view: ID = PM001

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Post some codes dude. (please do edit your question in order to post source)

Comment: Post some codes so we can help u

Answer (score 1):

Despite this is a really bad question, because in order to understand this you need to know fundamentals.

You probably did set up your id to auto-increment that means that every time you insert new record it is going to increment by one. To follow up please see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp).

That means you are storing integers ([whole numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WholeNumber.html)) in your database (table), therefore string `PM` is not going to be there. You fixed your problem by contacting strings; example from your code  `<td><?php echo "PM00".$u_key->ID; ?></td>`.

Your solution is simply not good because, what happens when you have 10 records in the table? Well, instead of showing `PM010` it is going to be `PM0010` I bet you do not want that.

To fix problem with leading zeros use function [str_pad();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) in your case:

```
<td><?php echo "PM".str_pad($u_key->ID, '3', '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);?></td>
```

> To make sure you understand, you will not see PM001 and PM002 and so on in your table! Instead, you will see simple integers 1, 2, 3...